# Transform keys and values in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 associative Arrays but they are in the wrong form. The first

```
Array(
    'name' => 'adam',
    'age' => '13'
)
```

and the second one shoulb be combined (merged?)

```
Array(
    'key' => 'pet',
    'value' => 'dog'
)
```

that the result would be like

```
Array(
    'name' => 'adam',
    'age' => '13',
    'pet' => 'dog'    
)
```

Can anyone give me a hint/solution?

EDIT: I did it that way:

```
$result = array_merge($item, array_column($metas, 'v', 'k'));
```

Thanks

Comment: `$a1[$a2['key']] = $a2['value']`…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data1 = Array(
    'name' => 'adam',
    'age' => '13'
);
$data2 = Array(
    'key' => 'pet',
    'value' => 'dog'
);
```

let $result=[];

```
foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
  $result[$data2['key']]=$data2['value'];
  $result=$data1+$result;
}
```

print_r($result);